# Neo4j cypher query is too slow(too many dbhits) in bidirectional relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Having the flowing data model:

```
(Phone{phoneNumber})-[:CALL]-(Phone{phoneNumber})        
(Person{personId})-[:KEEP]-(Phone{personId})    
(Case{caseId})-[:INVOLVE]-(Person{personId})
```

all these three are using bidirectional relationship. And created index on phoneNumber/personId/caseId.

User can input one or more strings which maybe represent as phoneNumber/
caseId/personId to query for their relationships(**NOT** consider direction and relationship depth can be 1 to 4).

Here is the cypher query:

```
match p = n-[r*1..4]-m 
with n,m,p 
where (n.phoneNumber in ["xxx","yyy"] 
       or n.caseSjNo in ["xxx","yyy"] 
       or n.identificationNumber in ["xxx","yyy"]) 
  and (m.phoneNumber in ["xxx","yyy"] 
       or m.caseSjNo in ["xxx","yyy"] 
       or m.identificationNumber in ["xxx","yyy"])
  and n <> m 
return p limit 1000
```

I profiled this query string in shell console.Having 10,000 nodes in neo4j db, I found the **Dbhits** is amazing. Here is the result(depth = 1 and depth = 4):

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ profile match p = n-[r*1..1]-m with n,m,p where (n.phoneNumber in ["XXX","YYY"] or n.caseSjNo in ["XXX","YYY"] or n.identificationNumber in ["XXX","YYY"]) and (m.phoneNumber in ["XXX","YYY"]                       or m.caseSjNo in ["XXX","YYY"]                       or m.identificationNumber in ["XXX","YYY"]) and n <> m return p limit 1000;
==> +---+
==> | p |
==> +---+
==> +---+
==> 0 row
==> 
==> ColumnFilter(0)
==>   |
==>   +Slice
==>     |
==>     +Filter
==>       |
==>       +ColumnFilter(1)
==>         |
==>         +ExtractPath
==>           |
==>           +TraversalMatcher
==> 
==> +------------------+-------+--------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
==> |         Operator |  Rows | DbHits | Identifiers |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               Other |
==> +------------------+-------+--------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
==> |  ColumnFilter(0) |     0 |      0 |             |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      keep columns p |
==> |            Slice |     0 |      0 |             |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       {  AUTOINT12} |
==> |           Filter |     0 | 480776 |             | ((((any(-_-INNER-_- in Collection(List({  AUTOSTRING0}, {  AUTOSTRING1})) where Property(n,phoneNumber(3)) == -_-INNER-_-) OR any(-_-INNER-_- in Collection(List({  AUTOSTRING2}, {  AUTOSTRING3})) where Property(n,caseSjNo(0)) == -_-INNER-_-)) OR any(-_-INNER-_- in Collection(List({  AUTOSTRING4}, {  AUTOSTRING5})) where Property(n,identificationNumber(2)) == -_-INNER-_-)) AND ((any(-_-INNER-_- in Collection(List({  AUTOSTRING6}, {  AUTOSTRING7})) where Property(m,phoneNumber(3)) == -_-INNER-_-) OR any(-_-INNER-_- in Collection(List({  AUTOSTRING8}, {  AUTOSTRING9})) where Property(m,caseSjNo(0)) == -_-INNER-_-)) OR any(-_-INNER-_- in Collection(List({  AUTOSTRING10}, {  AUTOSTRING11})) where Property(m,identificationNumber(2)) == -_-INNER-_-))) AND NOT(n == m)) |
==> |  ColumnFilter(1) | 20034 |      0 |             |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                keep columns n, m, p |
==> |      ExtractPath | 20034 |      0 |           p |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
==> | TraversalMatcher | 20034 |  50152 |             |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                m,   UNNAMED11, m, r |
==> +------------------+-------+--------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
==> 
==> Total database accesses: 530928

------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------
neo4j-sh (?)$ profile match p = n-[r*1..4]-m with n,m,p where (n.phoneNumber in ["XXX","YYY"] or n.caseSjNo in ["XXX","YYY"] or n.identificationNumber in ["XXX","YYY"]) and (m.phoneNumber in ["XXX","YYY"]                       or m.caseSjNo in ["XXX","YYY"]                       or m.identificationNumber in ["XXX","YYY"]) and n <> m return p limit 1000 ;
==> +---+
==> | p |
==> +---+
==> +---+
==> 0 row
==> 
==> ColumnFilter(0)
==>   |
==>   +Slice
==>     |
==>     +Filter
==>       |
==>       +ColumnFilter(1)
==>         |
==>         +ExtractPath
==>           |
==>           +TraversalMatcher
==> 
==> +------------------+---------+-----------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
==> |         Operator |    Rows |    DbHits | Identifiers |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               Other |
==> +------------------+---------+-----------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
==> |  ColumnFilter(0) |       0 |         0 |             |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      keep columns p |
==> |            Slice |       0 |         0 |             |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       {  AUTOINT12} |
==> |           Filter |       0 | 120244220 |             | ((((any(-_-INNER-_- in Collection(List({  AUTOSTRING0}, {  AUTOSTRING1})) where Property(n,phoneNumber(3)) == -_-INNER-_-) OR any(-_-INNER-_- in Collection(List({  AUTOSTRING2}, {  AUTOSTRING3})) where Property(n,caseSjNo(0)) == -_-INNER-_-)) OR any(-_-INNER-_- in Collection(List({  AUTOSTRING4}, {  AUTOSTRING5})) where Property(n,identificationNumber(2)) == -_-INNER-_-)) AND ((any(-_-INNER-_- in Collection(List({  AUTOSTRING6}, {  AUTOSTRING7})) where Property(m,phoneNumber(3)) == -_-INNER-_-) OR any(-_-INNER-_- in Collection(List({  AUTOSTRING8}, {  AUTOSTRING9})) where Property(m,caseSjNo(0)) == -_-INNER-_-)) OR any(-_-INNER-_- in Collection(List({  AUTOSTRING10}, {  AUTOSTRING11})) where Property(m,identificationNumber(2)) == -_-INNER-_-))) AND NOT(n == m)) |
==> |  ColumnFilter(1) | 5010178 |         0 |             |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                keep columns n, m, p |
==> |      ExtractPath | 5010178 |         0 |           p |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
==> | TraversalMatcher | 5010178 |  20070774 |             |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                m,   UNNAMED11, m, r |
==> +------------------+---------+-----------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
==> 
==> Total database accesses: 140314994
```

Although results came out, this took too long time.  Any tips of query optimization.

**UPDATE**
When having 1,000,000(1M) nodes in db, out of memory error occurred.

Comment: Which version are you using? How much heap and page-cache do you have configured?

Comment: @MichaelHunger Thanks. I am using 2.1.8 in windows. I can not configure heap size and page-cache using **neo4j-wrapper.conf** (seemed no effect). By the way, I put the neo4j-wrapper.conf file in **conf** folder under storeDirectory.

Comment: are you using the installer? don't "put config files somewhere" they should already be there and juste edited should be there in options. page cache is from Neo4j 2.2 and is in neo4j.properties.

Comment: @MichaelHunger Even using installer in windows, seems that **neo4j-wrapper.conf** file does not exist which used for heap size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you use bidirectional relationships in the first place? In Neo4j you can always navigate on both directions.

1. update to a recent Neo4j version (2.2.2)
2. use single directional relationships
3. use labels
4. create label indexes
5. the with in between doesn't help as it separates the conditions from the pattern
6. as you have a "generic" entity concept (x can be "anything") I recommend to add an :Entity label and use an id field there with an index.
7. are you really interested in all paths ? or just allShortestPaths?

see:

```
create index on :Entity(id);


match (n:Entity),(m:Entity) 
where n.id in ["xxx","yyy"] and m.id in ["xxx","yyy"] and n<>m
match p = (n)-[r*1..4]-(m)
return p 
limit 1000
```

#### Otherwise split it up into 6 different statements and use a union.

```
   match p = (n:Person)-[r*1..4]-(m:Case) 
   where n.identificationNumber in ["xxx","yyy"] and m.caseSjNo in ["xxx","yyy"]
   return p limit 500
   UNION
   match p = (n:Person)-[r*1..4]-(m:Phone) 
   where n.identificationNumber in ["xxx","yyy"] and m.phoneNumber in ["xxx","yyy"]
   return p limit 500
   UNION
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what does 'the with in between doesn't help as it separates the conditions from the pattern' mean?  Means with clause does not recommend?

Comment: It means that cypher will first compute all paths then "pass them on" aka WITH then filter, otherwise it's able to pull conditions into pattern matching

Comment: Thanks, got it. I did not know how to set label(:Entity) and update properties(id) on existed nodes, so I used the split solution. Seems that it must have n*(n+1)/2 statements.

Comment: which shoud be like this "MERGE (n:Person) ON MATCH SET n:Entity and n.id = n.identificationNumber" ? But invalid when ran it in console.

Comment: you should ask a new question for new things